# Where are save files stored for Doki Doki Literature Club?

Tags: doki-doki-literature-club

I want to transfer my save files for *Doki Doki Literature Club* to my new Windows desktop.

Where does Doki Doki Literature Club store save data? Can progress be transfered between computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

> For Windows it's %Appdata%\RenPy\DDLC-1454445547\

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/698780/discussions/0/1483232961033501549/)

---

Progress **should be** able to be transferred with a simple copy  and paste.

Comment: Which file should I copy though, the one with "Save File " on it?